# XSD with elements in any order and unbounded multiplicity

Tags: xsd

I have a requirement to produce an XSD.  Under the root element there can be 0, 1 or multiple occurrences of any of 7 different elements, and these elements can occur in any order.

I can't use sequence, since the elements are not necessarily in a predefined order.  This would be a valid schema, but it imposes too severe a restriction:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="data">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
```

I can't use all, since it doesn't allow maxOccurs to be unbounded, so this is an invalid schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="data">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:all>
<xs:element name="address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

I have a feeling I've come up against another limitation of XSD, but I just thought I'd ask as I am new to XML Schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `choice` block with a `maxOccurs="1"` on each element.  This will ensure there is at least one of either a, b, or c but no more than one from each.

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:element name="a" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <xs:element name="b" maxOccurs="1"/>
  <xs:element name="c" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xs:choice>
```

All of the following are valid under this schema:

```
<root>
    <a/>
</root>

<root>
    <a/>
    <b/>
</root>

<root>
    <b/>
    <a/>
</root>

<root>
    <c/>
    <a/>
</root>

<root>
    <a/>
    <c/>
    <b/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks Craig, that works.  I've actually used `minOccurs=0` as it would be acceptable (albeit unusual) to provide a file with just the root element and nothing else.

Comment: Two points of detail worth noting here:  (1) maxOccurs="1" is the default, so it needn't be specified explicitly, and (2) in a repeatable choice, maxOccurs has no effect on the set of valid instances:  (a|b)+ defines the same language as (a+|b+)+.  The key point in the solution is:  use a repeatable choice.

Comment: To be in line with your requirements, the choice should be minOccurs="0"

Comment: Yes you are right. I have used `minOccurs="0"` but I have removed all occurrences of `minOccurs="1"` and `maxOccurs="1"` and it still works.